# IntelliJ IDEA cannot format SQL code properly

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, code-formatting

I have reinstalled the last version of IntelliJ IDEA and then when I try to format an SQL file, it orders all the lines as shown on the image.

[image: My SQL file]

However, I have not made any settings for SQL formatting in the previous versions and the format was OK as shown on my current setting preview as shown below:

[image: My current settings]

So, is there anything default to format SQL properly? There are lots of choices in the settings, but I just want to use a default one available on the settings (I tried but it format almost the same).

Comment: @nameless_horse any reply about the format?

Comment: 1) This could be some 1-time glitch. Try restarting your computer -- sometimes this helps. 2) Try disabling all custom (not bundled by default) plugins. Any difference? 3) Try `File | Repair IDE` -- it has multiple steps and one of them may help. 4) If still nothing: try resetting your Settings to defaults: `File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...` -- it can make a backup before doing that.

Comment: P.S. You can copy your real code and paste it into the Code Style preview area. Will it format it there OK? Maybe it's something wrong with the file.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks a lot amigo. Your detailed answer is really helpful and I will give a try for all the steps you mentioned. At least, I see that there is no problem regarding to default settings, and as before, I do not need anything special to format sql code.

Comment: Any update on this? I am getting this glitch

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue. Settings/Languages&Frameworks/SQL Dialects, there you can find the dialect of the file. Change it to what you use.

That's how I solved the problem, even though you apply global or project SQL Dialect, the file may not be updated.

[image]

As you can see from the image, `Generic SQL` causes the problem.